# Parsing nested JSON objects from a JavaScript string

Tags: c#, json.net

OK, I'm totally new to JSON and [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) - so please forgive my ignorance;

I'm trying to parse a string which comes from a GET request into something useful for me in a C# application.

The string contains a structure with nested JSON objects. The objects on the first level has UTF-8 encodings like `\u0040` and escape characters like \. The next level contains another nested JSON object with double escape characters like `\\` and so on (down to 5 escape characters!)..

It also contains `&quot;` representations for quotation marks like ".

My first assumtion is that these are nested JSON objects. How can I parse these nested objects into something useful for me to query with, for instance, LINQ? Do I have to write the logic my self, or is there a nice function for this in Json.NET already?
The first bytes of the string to help clarify:

```
{\"phase\":2,\"id\":\"pagelet_search_results\",\"is_last\":true,\"css\":[\"Jo2rQ\",\"pxy5B\"],\"js\":[\"tVaAM\",\"rLVa6\",\"FJ3LF\"],\"resource_map\":{\"FJ3LF\":{\"type\":\"js\",\"src\":\"http:\\/\\/e.static.ak.fbcdn.net\\/rsrc.php\\/y8\\/p\\/r\\/1NVEOfjbXp5.js\"},\"pxy5B\":{\"type\":\"css\",\"permanent\":1,\"src\":\"http:\\/\\/f.static.ak.fbcdn.net\\/rsrc.php\\/yc\\/r\\/9H-KBGVNlw_.css\"}},\"onload\":[\"window.__UIControllerRegistry[\\\"c4d4ab726887b68c58602753\\\"] = new UIPagelet(\\\"c4d4ab726887b68c58602753\\\", \\\"\\\\\\/pagelet\\\\\\/generic.php\\\\\\/SearchObjectResultsPagelet\\\\\\/\\\", {\\\"params\\\":{\\\"viewerContext\\\":{\\\"userID\\\":123454549,\\\"accountID\\\":123454549,\\\"appID\\\":0,\\\"isOmnipotent\\\":false,\\\"isAuthenticated\\\":true,\\\"accessTokens\\\":[],\\\"instanceKey\\\":\\\"1254318719\\\\\\/1256318759\\\\\\/0\\\",\\\"originalViewerContext\\\":null,\\\"__index\\\":5,\\\"__sampleId\\\":null,\\\"__next\\\":-808,\\\"__state\\\":4,\\\"__preparer\\\":{\\\"runnablePreparables\\\":[],\\\"newRunnablePreparables\\\":[],\\\"blockedPreparables\\\":[],\\\"isRunning\\\":false,\\\"current\\\":null,\\\"isSequential\\\":false,\\\"round\\\":4,\\\"index\\\":3},\\\"__addedPreparers\\\":{\\\"3\\\":{\\\"runnablePreparables\\\":[],\\\"newRunnablePreparables\\\":[],\\\"blockedPreparables\\\":[],\\\"isRunning\\\":false,\\\"current\\\":null,\\\"isSequential\\\":false,\\\"round\\\":4,\\\"index\\\":3}},\\\"__siblings\\\":[],\\\"__children\\\":[],\\\"__ancestors\\\":[],\\
```

I appreciate your help, folks ;)

Comment: FYI there is a fully functional JSON serializer/deserializer in the FCL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you know the contract of the object you got, create a C# [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) class/classes with the same contracts and deserialize your JSON with JsonSerializer.Deserialize.
If the contract is unknown, try `JObject.Parse(jsonString)` and methods like `Values()` and `PropertyValues` will return you collection you can query with LINQ.

Answer (score -1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Ling;

.....


string js = "{\"phase\":2,\"id\":\"pagelet_search_results\"}";    
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
int phase = (int)jo.SelectToken("phase");
string id = (string)jo.SelectToken("id");
```